# eliminar elementos repetidos array

Tags: java

Mi intencion es la siguiente=El usuario nos pasa un array de ints(llamado enters) y nosotros empleando un metodo le tenemos que devolver un array con los valores que él ha introducido,con los que estén repetidos eliminados.
Aqui está mi codigo:

public int[] norepeticions(int[] enters){

```
    int contador=0;//longitud del nuevo array

    int[] unics=null;//array donde estaran los numeros sin repetir
```

//En este bucle definimos la longitud de el nuevo array(donde iran los numeros sin repetir

```
    for (int i = 0; i < enters.length-1; i++) {
        if(enters[i]==enters[i+1]){
            contador++;
        }

    }
    unics=new int[contador];
```

//en este bucle llenamos el array con los numeros sin repetir

```
    for (int i = 0; i < enters.length-1; i++) {
        if(enters[i]==enters[i+1]){
            unics[i]=enters[i];
        }

    }
    return unics;
}
```

y el output es el siguiente:

Contenido array introducido por usuario:
[ 1 2 3 2 ]
array sin repeticiones:
[ ]

Mi pregunta es:en qué he fallado?tengo algún error?hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

Comment: La verdad que la logica esta mal. Podrias tratar como ejercicio explicar que se supone que hace cada parte de tu codigo? creo que cuando hagas eso te vas a dar cuenta los errores de logica que tenes.

Comment: Puedes usar la clase Set de Java que funciona de manera similar a un array pero no permite duplicados. La documentación está en [la página oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) Cuando recibes el array en tu método para filtrar iteras sobre el array con un for y vas añadiendo a un Set con la función [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)). La función add añade elementos siempre y cuando no se encuentren ya en el conjunto. Una vez acabado el bucle del array ya tendrás el Set con los valores sin repetir y solo tendrás que usar la

Answer (score 2):

Si el usuario ingresó el arreglo [1,2,3,2], al recorrer el mismo mediante el for

```
for (int i = 0; i < enters.length-1; i++) {
    if(enters[i]==enters[i+1]){
        contador++;
    }

}
unics=new int[contador];
```

únicamente está comparando el elemento actual con el elemento siguiente, si los números repetidos no son son consecutivos no los va a contar, como en ejemplo. Tiene que comparar cada elemento con todos los elementos del arreglo, no sólo con el próximo y además tomar el cuenta que al compararlo con todos los elementos del arreglo en un punto se comparará con sí mismo y obviar esta situación.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una clase para **filtrar strings repetidos en un array**:

```
/** 
 * @file: Strings.php
 * 
 * @utor: Moisés Alcocer, 2016
 * @website: https://www.ironwoods.es
 * @license: http://www.apache.org/licenses/ - Apache License 2.0
 */

package app.helpers;

//imports

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



/** 
 * Class for replace string content according to a rules in an array
 * 
 */
public class Strings {

    /**********************************/
    /*** Properties declaration *******/

        private static List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();


    /**********************************/
    /*** Properties declaration *******/

        /**
         * Cleans the array of empty strings
         *
         * @param     arr   The arr
         * @return   The array
         */
        public static String[] delEmpties( String[] arr ) {

            res.clear();
            int len = arr.length;

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < len; i ++ ) {

                if ( ! arr[ i ].equals( "" ))
                    res.add( arr[ i ] );
            }


            return res.toArray( new String[ 0 ] );
        }

        /**
         * Filters the array of strings and delete repeat elements
         *
         * @param     arr   The arr
         * @return   The array
         */
        public static String[] filterRepeated( String[] arr ) {


            int len = arr.length;

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < len; i ++ ) {
                for ( int j = 0; j < ( len - 1 ); j ++ ) {

                    if ( i != j ) {
                        if ( arr[ i ].equals( arr[ j ] )) {
                            arr[ j ] = ""; //replace value by empty string
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }


            return delEmpties( arr );
        }

} //class
```

Deberías poder adaptar el código sin demasiado problema a otro tipo de elementos.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

para eliminar elementos repetidos de un array puedes hacerlo asi:

```
public static int[] sinRepetir(int[]a){
   Arrays.sort(a);
   int len = a.length;
   int j = 0;
   for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++){
       if(a[i]!=a[i+1]){
          a[j++] = a[i];
       }
   }
   a[j++] = a[len-1];
   int [] c = new int[j];
   for(int k = 0;k<j;k++){
   c[k] = a[k];
   }
   return c;
   }
```